# GraphQL using a dynamic ID from set of returned results to render correct set of data

Tags: graphql, sanity

I am pretty new to graphql, so my question might sound a bit strange. it may not be correct way of doing what I need, but I can't think of any other way.

Basically, I would like to know how I can use an ID i am being returned from my graphql query and use that ID in the second query to render the data I need.

currently my full query looks like:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query myQuery {
    allSanityFrontpage {
      nodes {
        content {
          ... on SanityHero {
            _key
            _type
            heroIntro
            heroHeader
            heroButtonText
            heroProjectReference {
              id
              title
              slug {
                current
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    sanityProject(id: { eq: "-8571b76b-8cfd-55cf-b848-151586f5c57a" }) {
      id
      title
      coverImage {
        asset {
          title
          fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
            ...GatsbySanityImageFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I am getting an ID returned from this part of the query

```
heroProjectReference {
              id
```

And currently I am using that ID statically to render the content I need by doing this:

```
sanityProject(id: { eq: "-8571b76b-8cfd-55cf-b848-151586f5c57a" }) {
      id
      title
```

How do I replace that static ID with something dynamic, so I can update my CMS and see whatever project I have updated it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side you must [call the chained queries serially](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/using-apollo-link-to-handle-dependent-queries/), populating the ID in the dependent query with the output from the first query.

Server-side, of course, you can combine the two in the resolver.